# css background image is not displaying bottom of the image

Tags: html, css

I have a css background image that i displayed as cover so that it covers entire screen but it does not show lower part of the image.

used this image: https://pixabay.com/vectors/winter-landscape-houses-background-2840549/

unable to see the lower part of the white houses in the screen.

using chrome browser.

CSS Code:

```
banner{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(./images/winter.png);
    background-size: cover; 
    background-repeat:
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

any help appreciated.

edit:
html code

```
<div class="banner" >                   
     <div class="navigation">    
        <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your html also

Comment: @HappyHands31 edited my answer to include html

Answer (score 1):

```css
body{
    background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/10/11/10/05/winter-2840549_960_720.png);
    
    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: tried this and again tried now with your code. but still i see same issue.
using chrome browser.

Comment: Actually you don't need a div to cover all of the screen. Could you test the updated code? @Rajesh.

Comment: updated dev element

Comment: @Rajesh you can use that `background-position: center bottom;`. This is proper solution for you, or change the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `background-size: cover;` to `background-size: contain;` and then `background-size: 100% 100%;` to fit 100% width.

```
body {
    background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/10/11/10/05/winter-2840549_960_720.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: i tried this and the image shows as stretched.

Comment: Yes - it will have to stretch in order to fit 100% width. Otherwise, get rid of `background-size: 100% 100%` and then your image will be centered. 

But I would actually suggest editing the image itself if you want the white portion at the bottom to show when using `background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having that the height of your image is bigger than the hight of the container (body element) at certain point depeding on the current viewport height, which causes your image to be cropped.

You can try the [background-size: contain](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_image_background1) where the image will scale and try to fit the container keeping the aspect ratio undisturbed. Here you gurantee that your image will not be cropped, but you need to consider changing the image for each device screen size ([responsive design image](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp)).

There are many ways to solve this issue, but you need to find the one that fits your design, or to find the image that fits your container.

Check this [w3schools](https:///*%20For%20devices%20smaller%20than%20400px:%20*/%20body%20%7B%20%20%20background-image:%20url(%27img_smallflower.jpg%27);%20%7D%20%20/*%20For%20devices%20400px%20and%20larger:%20*/%20@media%20only%20screen%20and%20(min-device-width:%20400px)%20%7B%20%20%20body%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20background-image:%20url(%27img_flowers.jpg%27);%20%20%20%7D%20%7D) article about responsive design image